# How can I make the program stop when the counter reaches a certain number in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

Below i have shared an example MIPS assembly program that reads a series of integers from the console. Valid entries are between -110 and 120 (inclusive). If an entry is invalid, the entry is rejected and an error message is printed to the screen. (for reference to understand the logic for your code). From this code, **I'd like to add one more thing that program will stop reading when count of numbers becomes 8.** Do you have any ideas?

```
#       Program Description

#  Reads integers from the keyboard and displays the total
#    number of entries, sum, and integer average
#  Reads until -1 is entered
#  Only accepts values between 10 and 99 (inclusive)
#

#  t0 = 0       # Total
#  t1 = 0       # Count
#  t2 = -110        # Min
#  t3 = 120     # Max
#  t4 = -467        # Stop
#
###########################################################
#       Register Usage
#   $t0  Running total
#   $t1  Entry count
#   $t2  Minimum value
#   $t3  Maximum value
#   $t4  Stop value
#   $t5  Entry (from user)
###########################################################
        .data
enter_p:  .asciiz "Enter a value between -110 and 120 (inclusive):  "
invalid_p:  .asciiz "Invalid value\n\n"
count_p:  .asciiz "\n\nNumber of entries:  "
total_p:  .asciiz "\nTotal:  "
average_p:  .asciiz "\nInteger average:  "
noentry_p:  .asciiz "\n\nNo valid values entered\n"

###########################################################
        .text
main:
    # Initialize values
    li $t0, 0       # Total
    li $t1, 0       # Count
    li $t2, -110        # Min value
    li $t3, 120     # Max value
    li $t4, -467        # Stop value

readLoop:
    # Get value
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, enter_p
    syscall         # Prompt for value
    li $v0, 5
    syscall         # Read entry

    # Validate value
    beq $v0, $t4, getResults
    blt $v0, $t2, entryInvalid
    bgt $v0, $t3, entryInvalid

    # If program gets here, the entry is valid
    add $t0, $t0, $v0   # Add entry to total
    addiu $t1, $t1, 1   # Increment counter

    b readLoop          # Loop

entryInvalid:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, invalid_p
    syscall         # Print error message

    b readLoop      # Go back and read more

getResults:
    beqz $t1, zeroEntries   # Prevent divide by 0

    # Display number of entries
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, count_p
    syscall         # Print 'count' string
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t1
    syscall         # Print count

    # Display total
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, total_p
    syscall         # Print 'total' string
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t0
    syscall         # Print total

    # Calculate and display average
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, average_p
    syscall         # Print 'average' string
    li $v0, 1
    div $a0, $t0, $t1   # Put results directly into $a0
    syscall         # Print average

    b mainEnd       # Done

zeroEntries:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, noentry_p
    syscall         # Print 'no entries' message

mainEnd:
    li $v0, 10      # End Program
    syscall
```

Comment: Simple: initialize a register to 0, increment it every time a value has been read, and jump out of the loop when the register's value reaches 8.

Comment: he already has the counter in `$t1`, so he needs only to add after `addiu $t1, $t1, 1` something like `beq $t1, 8, getResults` (8 must go to some register I suppose).

Comment: @Ped7g For speed, you _could_ put `8` in a reg (e.g. `$t7`) ahead of time and do `beq $t1,$t7,getResults` and it would be slightly faster. But _you_ actually coded a _correct_ form [the "immediate" form of the _pseudo-op_ version of `beq`]. It actually generates: `addiu $at,$zero,8` / `beq $t1,$at,getResults`. If `8` had non-zero bits in the upper word, the `addiu` would become two insts: `lui`/`ori` followed by the `beq` but it would still work. This `addiu` vs `lui/ori` is exactly what the `li` pseudo-op does.